# Trying to recreate webOS style navigation in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate the bottom app navigation bar that LG has in their WebOS for TV's. For those of you that are not familiar with this, a picture of it is below.

[image]

I created a container which sits at the bottom of the screen and then created ten or so  to be the "tiles." I then used transforms to tilt these to the right, but this has more problems such as me having to add crazy heights to the divs and them shoving each other down the screen etc.

Can anyone think of a better way to go about this? The code I've tried is below (shortened. I used SASS, by the way).

SASS/CSS:

```
.navigation{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;

    .bar{
        width: 10%;
        height: 600px;
        background: blue;
        @include rotate(-45deg);
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="navigation">
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `transform: skew(-25deg)` instead.

**Compatibility:** IE9 without skew and IE10+ with skew

- The text in the links is wrapped in a span
- The image is added before the span
- Both `img` and `span` are given `transform: skew(25deg)` to remove their distortion

**Important:** The float on the image element ensures that it does not affect the spans margin

### Example

Note how there is no white space between the opening and closing `<a>` element: `<a>link</a><a>link</a>`. [This is to prevent an inline gap.](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

```css
nav > a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 80px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
nav > a {
  transform: skew(-25deg);
  transform-origin: 0 90%; /* Control x-axis */
  transition: background 0.5s;
}
nav > a > span,
nav > a > img {
  transform: skew(25deg); /* Reverse Skew */
  display: block;
  margin-top: 120px;
  clear: left;
}
nav > a > img {
  margin: 50px 0 0 20px;
  float: left; /* Prevents the image from affecting the spans margin */
}
nav > a:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #F00;
}
nav > a:nth-child(even) {
  background: #F90;
}
nav > a:hover {
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="link">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/40" /><span>Link</span>
  </a><a href="link"><span>Link</span></a><a href="link"><span>Link</span></a><a href="link"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/40" /></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: This method looks good, but the behavior is tricky. Even when the links look skewed, they are still vertical, and that can confuse the user. For example: if you click on the top area of the red links, you may be clicking on the orange links and not on the red ones, causing an unexpected result

Comment: You're right, i didn't take that into account! On the phone now, so can't really edit, but the way around this is to apply the skew to the `<a>` element itself and then wrap the text and image children in a span element and skew them back to normal

Comment: I like it. It looks intuitive and simple, and it's easier to scale than my answer. Great  :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use SVG in HTML5. There is a small and [easy-to-follow tutorial in the w3schools website](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp).

Define a polygon with the shape that you want and add actions on any event, or animations using CSS. You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/x4ss9js3/

And the code is fairly simple (I added some animation):

```css
#menu0 { fill:blue; }
#menu1 { fill:red; }
#menu2 { fill:green; }
#menu3 { fill:orange; }

polygon {
    opacity:1;
    transition:opacity 1s;
    cursor:pointer;
}

polygon:hover {
    opacity:0.3;
    transition:opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<svg height="200" width="500">
    <polygon id="menu0" points="20,0 80,0 60,200 0,200" />
    <polygon id="menu1" points="80,0 140,0 120,200 60,200" />
    <polygon id="menu2" points="140,0 200,0 180,200 120,200" />
    <polygon id="menu3" points="200,0 260,0 240,200 180,200" />
</svg>
```